# SSIS Derived Column

Tags: ssis

How to convert a empty string into a string 
ie i have a column with names and in that column there are empty strings I want those empty strings to be removed and renamed as UNKNOWN.

Before :

```
ID    Name    Age
1             15
2     Sam     20
3             47   
4     Smith   25
```

After :

```
ID    Name     Age
1     UNKNOWN  15
2     Sam      20
3     UNKNOWN  47   
4     Smith    25
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an "if-else" expression in the derived column transform dialog. For example, you could try:

```
[Name] == ''?'UNKNOWN':[Name]
```

More info is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141069.aspx